# JavaFX transparent application screenshot

Tags: java, javafx, transparency

I need to make a screenshot of desktop in my application. Application shows transparent pane on whole screen and need to take a snapshot of user's dekstop.

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setOpacity(0.2);
```

I tried following code samples, using Snapshots.

```
SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
sp.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
...
ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(canvas.snapshot(sp, wi), null), "png", file);
```

But without any success. My pane on screenshots is not transparent, it's white instead. I've tried to use AWT Robot to this taks, but it also failed.

Comment: If you put your opacity to 1.0 do you still see white, or does it look normal?

Comment: Still white with any opacity value. I figure out an idea for this problem. I need to hide the app ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setIconified-boolean-), make a screenshot using external tool and then bring the app window back. It was a part of this app, but it didn't work well on Linux. I needed to fix the hide/show part and it is working now.